# Recursively create empty files in all empty 'leaf' sub-directories

Tags: bash, command-line

I have created the directory structure for my `Maven` project.

```
$ tree -a -I .git
.
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources

7 directories, 2 files
```

Now I'd like to persist the structure to `.git`, which requires creating *dummy files* in sub-directories. How can I (recursively) add empty `.gitkeep` files to all *empty sub-directories*?

---

Following questions already discuss (recursive) creation of empty files in sub-directories, but I'd like the **files to be created only in **leaf directories** and not in any *intermediate directories***

- [Creating empty files in all subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935764)
- [Recursively add a file to all sub-directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94207)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Ryan Armstrong's blog](http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/recursively-create-gitkeep-files.html), here's how you do it with GNU `find` or compatible:

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

- `find . -type d` (recursively) looks for directories under current path
- `-empty` filters out directories that already contain something
- `-not -path "./.git/*"` ensures no files are created inside `.git` directory
- `-exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;` creates empty `.gitkeep` file in each directory matching above criteria

---

The resulting structure looks like

```
$ tree -a -I .git
.
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── .gitkeep
    │   └── resources
    │       └── .gitkeep
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── .gitkeep
        └── resources
            └── .gitkeep

7 directories, 7 files
```

Answer (score 0):

With zsh:

```
() {touch -- $^@/.gitkeep} **/*(/^F)
```

Where:

- `**/`: any amount (including 0) of subdirectories (recursive globing). Note that hidden files and directories are ignored by default.
- `(/^F)`: glob qualifiers with:

  - `/`: files of type *directory*
  - `^F`: not `F`ull (empty)
- `{} {body} arguments`: anonymous functions:
- `$^@`: `$@` with `rc_expand_param` enabled so that `$^@/.gitkeep` expands to the same as `$1/.gitkeep` `$2/.gitkeep`... `$n/.gitkeep` instead of `$1` `$2`... `$n/.gitkeep` as it would do otherwise.